Div "doesnt exist" when trying to check if user can see it
On my chatting service, I'm checking if the person is at the bottom of the chat by putting a div with id "bottom" there and checking if the user can see it. The first time I do it, everything works fine. Second time and more, it gives me an error saying the "bottom" div is null. I cant figure out whats wrong with it.
Heres the JS code
function updateMessages() {
    var messages = document.getElementById("messages");
    if(messages && document.getElementById("bottom")) { // Check if messages and bottom div exist
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                scroll = messages.scrollTop;
                var messagesRect = messages.getBoundingClientRect();
                var bottomRect = document.getElementById("bottom").getBoundingClientRect();
                console.log(messagesRect);
                console.log(bottomRect);
                var isVisible = (bottomRect.top >= messagesRect.top && bottomRect.bottom <= messagesRect.bottom);

                if (isVisible) {
                    console.log("returned at bottom");
                    messages.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;
                } else {
                    console.log("returned not at bottom");
                    messages.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    messages.scrollTop = scroll;
                }
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "Dont want to share this link", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    } else {
        console.log("doesnt exist");
        if (!messages) {
            console.log("messages");
        } 
        if (!document.getElementById("bottom")) {
            console.log("bottom");
        }
    }
}
setInterval(updateMessages, 6000);

And the console logs:
First updateMessages();
DOMRect {x: 0, y: 146, width: 1149, height: 660, top: 146, …}
DOMRect {x: 5, y: 791, width: 1124, height: 2, top: 791, …}
returned at bottom

second updateMessages()
doesnt exist
bottom

HTML:
<div class="row content" id="messages" style="display: block;">
  <div id="bottom"><hr></div>
  message 1
</div>


Please [edit] your question to include the relevant html.

messages.innerHTML = obliterates your bottom dev as it's inside messages dev

Well, somehow your "bottom" div is disappearing between the first (successful) and second (unsuccessful) execution of your updateMessages() function.
What is the structure of the DIVs? My guess is that it would be something like this:
<div id=messages>
    <div id=bottom></div>
</div>

Because in this case, when you do:
messages.innerHTML = this.responseText;

then the "bottom" div gets destroyed... unless you're getting another one in the responseText.
